# Redux and the 3rd party libraries

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, flux, ngxs

We are building an admin panel, and we took ngx-admin as a base.

I want to use @ngxs/store in the project.
But the admin panel have got 3rd party libraries and components, which are not working in the redux-way.

Should I use the @ngxs/store ?
How can I control actions from 3rd party libraries?
Or @ngxs/store is need for projects, which are not using 3rd party components?

For example, it uses ng2-smart-table.
The table have got a sorting, filtering etc.
All of these actions should be a redux Actions, and they should have the apropriate reducers.
But the component is ready to use, and doesn't know anything about the global state and do not have any methods to use it...

So, the question is, should I use @ngxs/store, or I should go native Angular and leave Redux only for self-written application without using 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.

If you want to implement Redux and keep track of everything you will need to create actions yourself for 3rd party components. But keep in mind that for a table you might not need actions for everything, and store only the rows data you are going to display.

Comment: Yes, but if I have an external auth component, which needs only an url and some fields descriptions to pass? But it stores and reads the token under the hood? How then can I monitor the state of logged-in or logged-out user from the store? I have to ask everytime the component, is the user logged in or no etc..

Comment: Well I don't know the ngx-admin architecture itself, but if their services don't expose some hooks to tap into, you have no way to change their behavior.

A different thing is when it comes to components, where you usually provide the state itself, and that can be done through Redux indeed.

Comment: sad, but it do not supports the redux architecture. the ngx-admin itself uses *nebular*, *ng2-smart-table* and other 3rd party components

Comment: for example, what can be done for the nebular auth service?

Comment: Not sure what your goal is. A theme is used to delegate architectural choices, but it seems like you're trying to force your architecture choice to a theme. If instead you need only to tap into specific features (such as if user is logged in) you should just use the provided services, `NbAuthService` in this case.